# Moving from socko to akka-http websockets

Tags: scala, websocket, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have an existing akka application built on socko websockets. Communication with the sockets takes place inside a single actor and messages both leaving and entering the actor (incoming and outgoing messages, respectively) are labelled with the socket id, which is a first class property of a socko websocket (in socko a connection request arrives labelled with the id, and all the lifecycle transitions such as handshaking, disconnection, incoming frames etc. are similarly labelled)

I'd like to reimplement this single actor using akka-http (socko is more-or-less abandonware these days, for obvious reasons) but it's not straightforward because the two libraries are conceptually very different; akka-http hides the lower level details of the handshaking, disconnection etc, simply sending whichever actor was bound to the http server an UpgradeToWebsocket request header. The header object contains a method that takes a materialized Flow as a handler for all messages exchanged with the client.

So far, so good; I am able to receive messages on the web socket and reply them directly. The official examples all assume some kind of stateless request-reply model, so I'm struggling with understanding how to make the next step to assigning a label to the materialized flow, managing its lifecycle and connection state (I need to inform other actors in the application when a connection is dropped by a client, as well as label the messages.)

The alternative (remodelling the whole application using akka-streams) is far too big a job, so any advice about how to keep track of the sockets would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from Rüdiger Klaehn was a useful starting point, thanks!

In the end I went with `ActorPublisher` after reading another question here ([Pushing messages via web sockets with akka http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634283/pushing-messages-via-web-sockets-with-akka-http/)).

The key thing is that the Flow is 'materialized' somewhere under the hood of akka-http, so you need to pass into `UpgradeToWebSocket.handleMessagesWithSinkSource` a Source/Sink pair that already know about an existing actor. So I create an actor (which implements `ActorPublisher[TextMessage.Strict]`) and then wrap it in `Source.fromPublisher(ActorPublisher(myActor))`.

When you want to inject a message into the stream from the actor's `receive` method you first check if `totalDemand > 0` (i.e. the stream is willing to accept input) and if so, call `onNext` with the contents of the message.

Answer (score 3):

To interface with an existing actor-based system, you should look at [`Source.actorRef`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.6/scala/stream/stream-integrations.html#source-actorref) and [`Sink.actorRef`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.6/scala/stream/stream-integrations.html#Sink_actorRef). `Source.actorRef` creates an ActorRef that you can send messages to, and `Sink.actorRef` allows you to process the incoming messages using an actor and also to detect closing of the websocket.

To connect the actor created by `Source.actorRef` to the existing long-lived actor, use [`Flow#mapMaterializedValue`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.6/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow@mapMaterializedValue%5BMat2%5D(f:Mat=%3EMat2):Flow.this.ReprMat%5BOut,Mat2%5D). This would also be a good place to assign an unique id for a socket connection.

This [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954538/how-to-send-a-message-in-a-reactive-stream-from-a-subscriber-to-a-publisher-in-a) might get you started.

One thing to be aware of. The current websocket implementation does *not* close the server to client flow when the client to server flow is closed using a [websocket close message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.1). There is an [issue](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/19359) open to implement this, but until it is implemented you have to do this yourself. For example by having [something like this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128289/akka-streams-bidirectional-flow-that-completes-the-stage-when-one-side-is-compl) in your protocol stack.